# Mongo native driver toArray() on limit(1)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

According to the documentation the official way to retrieve one document via a Promise is `.find().limit(1).toArray()` according to the examples here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#find

I find it annoying that they have forced a single result when returning a Promise into an array. Unlike the following method `find().limit(1).next(function(err, doc){})` which returns the single document. *Anyway around this, or is it just to adapt?*

Also, findOne is depreciated here https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOne and states the following should be used: `find().limit(1).next(function(err, doc){})`. However here https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#find it states in the examples to use `then()`.

*So, should I use `next()` or `then()`?*

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find().limit(1).toArray().then(arrs =>{return arrs[0] || null });` if you want to return single object;

`collection.find()` query all match document return a array object;